# return JSON queryset for search

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write a function to search and display its result as a JSON format to the user.

Currently, I am doing the search successfully from the database and I can find and list down the data from the database in products attribute. 
But I have the issue of displaying the results as I return the list of products from the database.

```
def search_titles(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        search_text = request.POST['search_text']
    else:
        search_text =  ''

    products = Product.objects.filter(title__contains = search_text)

    return HttpResponse(json.dump(products), content_type = 'application/json')
```

I cannot display the results to the user. How to return the products list and display the items?

Comment: two questions: 1) how is this displaying to the user currently? 2) are you using Django's built-in templating or a JS framework?

Comment: Hi @Zach, 1) I cannot display it to the user now. I am able to display it with render_to_response and returning result in HTML format using:                         
 "return render_to_response('ajax_search.html',{'products': products})" but it doesnot have good view. 2) I am using Django's built-in templating

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at [jsonresponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects1) :

```
def search_titles(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        search_text = request.POST['search_text']
    else:
        search_text =  ''

    products = Product.objects.filter(title__contains = search_text)
    products = list(products)  # important: convert the QuerySet to a list object

    return JsonResponse({'products':products})
```

With HttpResponse:

```
def search_titles(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        search_text = request.POST['search_text']
    else:
        search_text =  ''

    products = Product.objects.filter(title__contains = search_text)
    products = serializers.serialize('json', products)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(products), content_type = 'application/json')
```

Note : I used json.dumps() and not json.dump() which needs a file object and dump JSON to it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. using JSON response I get this error: "dump() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fp'"

Comment: I get this error: "Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable"

Comment: Thank you. I think serializer is enough and we don't need to dumps again products to JSON." return HttpResponse(products, content_type = 'application/json') is returning JSON format of data. But still I find this information after inspecting the page and I cannot display it to the user.

Comment: That's a different problem...post the code you are using to display the data please